# Blocked by CORS policy: 405 unsupported method in OPTIONS - ASP.NET Core Edition

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services, cors

When calling on my webservices using JQuery AJAX I receive a message in the browser console logs that it has been blocked by CORS policy and it does not have HTTP ok status.

[CORS Policy error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G93K1.png)

In my web.config file and by checking the response headers in the network tab I have defined the following,

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,iac-version,license

[Network response in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCUaa.png)

Looking at the status code Chrome is reporting a 405 Method Not Allowed and not a 200 OK. Chrome is also requesting the OPTIONS method which is an allowed method.

This leads me to believe the issue is the webservice code not allowing the method or not sending back a 200 OK.

In the /api/InboundAction controller I have created an Options endpoint that simply returns back a 200 status code in the response with a blank output.

```
[HttpOptions]
[AllowAnonymous]
public object Options()
{
    HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    //HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    return null;
}
```

Now when I do an OPTIONS call in Postman I also get the 405 status code with an error message pasted below so that matches with what Chrome is reporting.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
        "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://***/api/InboundAction' does not support HTTP method 'OPTIONS'.",
        "innerError": null
    }
}
```

Something in the code is preventing the OPTIONS method from being valid. I'll update this with my solution if I find any but wanted to throw my current knowledge out there in case anyone bumped into the same problem in ASP.NET Core. Thanks

Tried making an AJAX call and was expecting results from my webservice but got a CORS policy error.

Tried updating the web.config file with access origin, methods, and headers, then modified the ASP.NET Core OPTIONS endpoint to return status 200 OK but still receiving the CORS policy error.

Comment: Have you configure [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in your program.cs or startup.cs file in your project?

Comment: Perhaps one or more of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-core%5D+%5Bcors%5D+405+is%3Aanswer might help.